# Are there any generators that support OpenAPI 3?

Tags: swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

At the time of writing this the OpenAPI 3 spec is relatively new. I am struggling to find any documentation generators that support version 3.0.

Does anyone know of generators that support OpenAPI v3.0?

Comment: Known 3.0-compatible tools are listed in [IMPLEMENTATIONS.md](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/IMPLEMENTATIONS.md).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try OpenAPI Generator (https://openapi-generator.tech), which supports both OpenAPI spec v2, v3 and released a stable version (3.0.0) a few days ago.

Using docker, you can easily generate the API documentation:

```
docker run --rm -v ${PWD}:/local openapitools/openapi-generator-cli generate \
    -i https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openapitools/openapi-generator/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/test/resources/2_0/petstore.yaml \
    -g html2 \
    -o /local/out/html2
```

Comment: @MattC I would advice you to consider this more recent answer

Answer (score 3):

You will find a curated list of tools and libraries in the [OAI Implementations document](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/IMPLEMENTATIONS.md) found at GitHub.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged.  Please consider listing some here in your post.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I'm new to contributing to Stack Overflow.  Have used it for many years as a consumer, though.

Comment: Helen's answer to the question is correct, but it appears as a comment and not an answer per se.  My earlier post only duplicates Helen's response as an answer.  Nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of new developments to add:

- [RepreZen API Studio](http://rzen.io/codegen) now supports OpenAPI-Generator, referenced above by William. (Note: I work for RepreZen.)
- [OpenAPI.Tools](http://openapi.tools) is another great resource for OpenAPI v3-compatible editors, generators, doc formats, and other tools.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, I found it very useful for node.js express projects

**oas-generator** for Open API 3.0 spec: [Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oas-generator)